# Xamarin :: Drag and Drop works only once

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5CgQUbnf1Qk).

At minute 4:25 he easily drag and drop in the order:

1. a TextView
2. a Button
3. a Button

I can only drag and drop the TextView and then there's nothing else I can drop in.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you used `RelativeLayout`, If you change the `LinearLayout` and set `android:orientation="vertical"` for your `LinearLayout`, you can drop many times.

[image]